# I get errors when trying to run my flask app in AWS Lambda

Tags: python, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I am trying to deploy a flask app that run very well locally to AWS Lambda using `severless`. The deployment is good but I can't use the aws lambda app . I get an error `502 Bad Gateway` `message: Internal server error`.

I checked the logs and here what I found :

```
2021-03-12T01:49:27.685+01:00   Traceback (most recent call last):

2021-03-12T01:49:27.685+01:00   File "/var/task/wsgi_handler.py", line 44, in import_app

2021-03-12T01:49:27.685+01:00   wsgi_module = importlib.import_module(wsgi_fqn_parts[-1])

2021-03-12T01:49:27.685+01:00   File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module

2021-03-12T01:49:27.685+01:00   return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)

2021-03-12T01:49:27.685+01:00   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import

2021-03-12T01:49:27.685+01:00   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load

2021-03-12T01:49:27.685+01:00   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked

2021-03-12T01:49:27.685+01:00   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked

2021-03-12T01:49:27.685+01:00   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module

2021-03-12T01:49:27.685+01:00   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed

2021-03-12T01:49:27.685+01:00   File "/var/task/app.py", line 10, in <module>

2021-03-12T01:49:27.685+01:00   from common.helpers import *

2021-03-12T01:49:27.685+01:00   File "/var/task/common/helpers.py", line 1, in <module>

2021-03-12T01:49:27.685+01:00   from common.db import db

2021-03-12T01:49:27.685+01:00   File "/var/task/common/db.py", line 1, in <module>

2021-03-12T01:49:27.685+01:00   from flask_pymongo import pymongo

2021-03-12T01:49:27.685+01:00   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_pymongo'

2021-03-12T01:49:27.686+01:00   [ERROR] Exception: Unable to import app.app Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/imp.py", line 234, in load_module     return load_source(name, filename, file)   File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/imp.py", line 171, in load_source     module = _load(spec)   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 702, in _load   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed   File "/var/task/wsgi_handler.py", line 119, in <module>     wsgi_app = import_app(config)   File "/var/task/wsgi_handler.py", line 49, in import_app     raise Exception("Unable to import {}".format(config["app"]))

2021-03-12T01:49:27.803+01:00   START RequestId: cd231555-23cb-4444-b6fe-36e2ce590dc7 Version: $LATEST

2021-03-12T01:49:29.040+01:00   Traceback (most recent call last):

2021-03-12T01:49:29.040+01:00   File "/var/task/wsgi_handler.py", line 44, in import_app

2021-03-12T01:49:29.040+01:00   wsgi_module = importlib.import_module(wsgi_fqn_parts[-1])

2021-03-12T01:49:29.040+01:00   File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module

2021-03-12T01:49:29.040+01:00   return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)

2021-03-12T01:49:29.040+01:00   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import

2021-03-12T01:49:29.040+01:00   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load

2021-03-12T01:49:29.040+01:00   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked

2021-03-12T01:49:29.040+01:00   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked

2021-03-12T01:49:29.040+01:00   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module

2021-03-12T01:49:29.040+01:00   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed

2021-03-12T01:49:29.040+01:00   File "/var/task/app.py", line 10, in <module>

2021-03-12T01:49:29.040+01:00   from common.helpers import *

2021-03-12T01:49:29.040+01:00   File "/var/task/common/helpers.py", line 1, in <module>

2021-03-12T01:49:29.040+01:00   from common.db import db
```

I don't understand `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_pymongo'` When I use the app in local I don't have this. I've tried to install it anyway but it still doesn't work.

My `serverless` config :

```
service: serverless-flask
plugins:
  - serverless-python-requirements
  - serverless-wsgi
custom:
  wsgi:
    # This is the file name and the app name of the application 
    # Where file name is app.py and Flask app name is app
    # ie. app = Flask(__name__) 
    app: app.app
    packRequirements: false
  pythonRequirements:
    dockerizePip: non-linux
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.8
  stage: dev
  region: us-east-1
functions:
  app:
    handler: wsgi.handler
    events:
      - http: ANY /
      - http: 'ANY {proxy+}'
```

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try packaging & installing your module in a containerised lambda env.

As sometimes modules packed in windows will not work on other os.

I had a similar issue with psycopg2 then installed and packaged in [lambci docker](https://github.com/lambci/docker-lambda) and everything was working fine.

Comment: I am on Mac OS so I am not sure this solution will be useful in my situation. Am I wrong ?

Comment: If you've the module in the source bundle but still getting module not found error means the above might be the issue. It is not specific to windows actually it is lambda env vs others

Comment: It doesn't work. I am using the `serverless framework` (not zappa by the way). It's curious . The `pymongo` import is located in a separated file from my `app.py` in a file named `db.py`. Maybe this is the reason it doesn't work.

Comment: If possible can you add that code snippet in the post